# How to query MySQL Record value to Python Variables?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to give python variables with values that I fetch from MySQL database.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python -u
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import time
import datetime
import mysql.connector
import sys

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "admin",
    password = "admin",
    db = "testonly"
)
mycursor = db.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp = 0
    mycursor.execute("SELECT temperature FROM table ORDER BY primarykey DESC LIMIT 1;") #By selecting one column in a row, I fetch only one record from the talbe.
    data = mycursor.fetchone()
    for temperature in data:
        print(temperature)

    temp = data['temperature']

    sys.exit()
```

Then I have error like so:

```
File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    temp = data['temperature']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

In which way I can give value to python variable for later usage?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `fetchone` returns a tuple with the data from your database. As it currently stands, you need to access your data by index

```
temp = data[0]
```

If you want to access your data by the `temperature` key, you need to use specify your cursor

```
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursorDict
...

mycursor = db.cursor(cursor_class=MySQLCursorDict)

...

temp = data['temperature']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object `data` is a tuple and can't be referenced like that. You need to use this:

```
temp = data[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. What if I want to query 2 values in one selection?

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT temperature，pressure FROM table ORDER BY primarykey DESC LIMIT 1;")
    data = mycursor.fetchone()
    for x in data:
        print(temperature, pressure)
    
    temp = data[0]
    pres = data[1]

```

Comment: As in you want to select two or more columns? You can do it through indexing. Example: data[:2]   Have I understood your question correctly?

Comment: Yes, I want to select 2 columns, and I want to give it's values to 2 seperate variables in one selection.

Comment: I guess tuple unpacking should work for you since there are only two variables.  Please try this:    `temp , press = data`